# GPS/Network Location of SQLite entry

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, android-fragments, gps

Hello I have a question for a class project app I am working on. I have a Notes app that pretty simply records text input from edit texts into a SQLite database and then retrieves each of them to a list fragment for the user to view. They can also click on each list item and that opens another fragment that displays the "details" of the entry, i.e. Subject, body content, time, and date entered. I want to make an addition that records user's current GPS/Network location for that particular entry (geotagging). I have a floating action button in the note details fragment that should link to a Map fragment with a marker on it corresponding to the location recorded when that entry was made. I'm fairly new to Android so still learning about all this. Just a bit hung up on this. Does anyone have a good explanation on how to save location into that same database (lat, long) when the entry is submitted, and then when the user clicks the FAB in details fragment, it displays a map with location marker for each respective entry? Please let me know if anyone can help, or if any of my database classes are needed?

Also want to add that I have indeed looked in quite a few places on Google, but I'm not quite sure if maybe I am using the wrong terminology or what, but results seems to be off for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a class for getting the location:

```
public class MyLocation {
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
private Timer timer1;
private LocationManager lm;
private LocationResult locationResult;
private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;
private String[] permissions = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
};

public boolean getLocation(final Context context, LocationResult result) {
    //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
    locationResult = result;
    if (lm == null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        return false;
    try {
        boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
        for(int i=0; i<permissions.length;i++) {
            if(!Utils.PermissionGranted(permissions[i], context)) allPermissionsGranted = false;
        }
        if(!allPermissionsGranted) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
                }
            });
        }
        if (network_enabled) {
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Utils.Toast(context, e.getMessage());
    }
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 5000);

    return true;
}

private LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

private LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};

private class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

        Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
        if(gps_enabled)
            gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(network_enabled)
            net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        //if there are both values use the latest one
        if(gps_loc != null && net_loc != null){
            if(gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            else
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }

        if(gps_loc != null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
            return;
        }
        if(net_loc != null){
            locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
            return;
        }
        locationResult.gotLocation(null);
    }
}

public static abstract class LocationResult{
    public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
}
}
```

When you are about to add a new note just do:

```
MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult(){ 
        @Override 
        public void gotLocation(Location location){ 
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    //Any UI related code 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    };
```

Then for the map:

Go to https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html. You have to add a marker for every location in your database.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! Do you recommend just adding that gotLocation() code in the second snippet to the existing submit button's code for submitting the diary entry?

Comment: It's probably the best moment.

Comment: awesome! making more and more sense.And I need to create another column name in my table to hold these locations, correct?

Comment: 2 columns, one for lat and one for long

Comment: when you say UI related code, do you mean actually setting those lat, long column values to textviews? because from what I have been reading, the drawing of markers on the map is done in the actual MapActivity.

Comment: I get these two types of errors from the first code snippet:                               `Error:(55, 27) The method PermissionGranted(String, Context) is undefined for the type Utils`    `Error:(78, 19) The method Toast(Context, String) is undefined for the type Utils`

Comment: public abstract class Utils {

    public static boolean PermissionGranted(String permission, Context context) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public static void Toast(final Context context, final String msg) {
        Utils.Toast(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    public static void Toast(Context context, String msg, int length) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, length).show();
    }

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it